# Probability of touching a specific ball at least once in 100 tries from a box of 100 well mixed balls.

Tags: probability

We have a box which contains 99 red balls and 1 green ball.  The box is shaken vigorously such that each ball has an equal chance of being touched.

A guy with covered eyes goes to touch one ball but the ball is not taken from the box, rather it stays in the box.  He does not know which ball he is touching.

After touching the ball, the box get shaken vigorously again such that each ball again has an equal chance of being touched on the next try.

This process of touching a ball and shaking vigorously is repeated until 100 tries total have occurred.

What is the probability that the guy touched the green ball at least once in those 100 tries?

Comment: You don't mention the question in the title in the text at all. Please state your question in the question text or edit the title. A title is something that people use to see what the content is about, and it should never contain any new stuff.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what title I should put, can you recommend a title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $99$% chance of him touching a red ball each of the $100$ times and only a $1$% chance of touching a green ball each time.  To not touch a green ball in $100$ tries, he must touch a red ball all $100$ times.  The prob of that is $0.99^{100}$. Therefore the prob of touching the green ball at least once in the $100$ tries is $100$% - $0.99^{100}$.  Note that as you do more and more tries, the chances of touching a green ball get better and better but will never be $100$% sure thing.  He could touch $300$ balls for example and still not touch a green cuz the prob he will touch at least one green is about $95$%.  One might wrongly think that since there is a $1$% chance of touching a green each try that in $100$ tries, he is guaranteed to touch a green since $100$ * $1$% = $100$% but this is not true because that is not the proper way to calculate the prob.

I hope my explanation helps.

Comment: Check out the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

The probability that he didn't touch the green ball is equal to $(99/100)^{100}$. Then the probability that he touched the green ball at least once is equal to
$$
1-\biggl(\frac{99}{100}\biggr)^{100}\approx0.63.
$$

Comment: 0.63 out of 100? can I get more explanation

Comment: 1 is 100% sure, 0 is 0% sure. The 0.63 means that about 63% of the times (63% of when you do 100 times), he touches the green ball once or more.

Comment: @q8phantom The probability that he touches the green ball is $1/100$ and the probability that he touches a red ball is equal to $99/100$. If he performs this experiment independently $100$ times, then the probability that he doesn't touch the green ball is equal to $(99/100)^{100}$. The [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event) of this event is the event that he touched the green ball at least once. Then the probability is given by $1-(99/100)^{100}\approx0.63$.